# GridLayout of Button on ImageView

Tags: android, grid-layout

What I'm trying to display to the screen is Image and buttons that cover the image and enable the user clicks on the buttons and slowly reveals the image behind the buttons.
The problem that the button does not appear at all,can not be seen at all.
In addition to that, I need x * x buttons that will fit to cover the whole image evenly.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/cat">

<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="4">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:text="W"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="@drawable/signalsquare"
        />


</GridLayout>
```

This image is for demonstration purposes(sorry for the lack of symmetry in the buttons)

At first the user sees the image covered with buttons,then each click of each button reveals another small part of the image

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244363/discussion-on-question-by-nflx-gridlayout-of-button-on-imageview).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/questions" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/q"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/w"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/q"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/w"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/q"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/w"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/q"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/w"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/e"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/r"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="W"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:background="@drawable/button_design"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, only the button should be a real square, to cover everything

Comment: ok i am sharing the code

Comment: You just need to change the size of the picture and the buttons will take shape accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much, in a few more hours I will be able to check the code in my project and check if I have succeeded

Comment: if i was able to help, can you give a +1 vote and click the tick